# How to use a derived class attribute in the base class? C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've got these two classes:

```cs
abstract class BaseModel
{
  ...
  public List<String> fields;
  ...
  public DataSet select(){
    //ex : this here the fields is null; but this class being abstract means
    // I can only call this from an inherited class of this (child class)
    // which will have the fields attributes override
    this.fields.Count();
  }
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
  public new List<String> fields = new List<String> {
    "id",
    "email",
    "name",
    "password"
  };
}
```

If I create a new instance of `User`, and then call the `select` method, I get a `null` error.
Am I overwriting the fields attribute the wrong way?

Comment: Don't create a new field. Insted, fill it in the derived constructor.

Comment: terminology: your "fields" is a field. not an attribute in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class User : BaseModel
{
  public new List<String> fields = ...
}
```

You are using `new`, which does the exact opposite of what you want. `new` declares this field to be **unrelated** to any similarly named field in any base class.

There are a few approaches that you can use here. In order of my personal preference:

Don't re-declare the field and instead use the constructor:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public List<String> fields = new List<string>();
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
    public User()
    {
        fields.AddRange(new List<String> {
            "id",
            "email",
            "name",
            "password"
        });
    }
}
```

You can also use the base constructor. Maybe not necessary here but sometimes a cleaner approach. The nice thing here is that your base class can **force** your derived class to pass in a list of fields, which prevents developers forgetting and introducing bugs.

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public List<String> fields;

    public BaseModel(List<String> fieldsList)
    {
        this.fields = fieldsList;
    }
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
    public User() : base(new List<String> { "id", "email", "name", "password" })
    {

    }
}
```

Set the base **property** (not field!) as `virtual` (or `abstract`) and override it in the derived class:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public virtual List<String> fields { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
    public override List<String> fields { get; set; } = new List<String> { "id", "email", "name", "password" };
}
```

`abstract` would've worked here as well.

You can also use a method instead of a property here. Not that properties can't be overridden, but it's more commonly done with methods:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public virtual List<String> GetFields()
    {
        return new List<String>();
    }
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
    public override List<String> GetFields()
    {
        return new List<String> {
            "id",
            "email",
            "name",
            "password"
        };
    }
}
```

`abstract` would've worked here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use constructor in `User` class and access property from `BaseModel`:

```
public class User : BaseModel
{
    public User()
    {
        fields = new List<String> {
            "id",
            "email",
            "name",
            "password"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplest and most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare an abstract method GetFields in BaseModel and override it in all subclasses:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public abstract List<String> GetFields();
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
    private static readonly List<String> FIELDS = 
            new List<String>{"id", "email", "name", "password"};

    public override List<String> GetFields()
    {
        return FIELDS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help https://dotnetfiddle.net/1crFh2

```
    public abstract class BaseModel
    {
        public List<String> fields = new List<string>();

        public int select()
        {
            //ex : this here the fields is null; but this class being abstract means
            // I can only call this from an inherited class of this (child class)
            // which will have the fields attributes override
            return this.fields.Count();
        }
    }

    public class User : BaseModel
    {

        public User()
        {
            var theFields = new List<String> {
                "id",
                "email",
                "name",
                "password"
            };
            fields.AddRange(theFields);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var user = new User();
            var q = user.select();
        }
    }
```